# Sencha Touch automatic list sizing

Tags: list, mobile, sencha-touch

Im new to programming and Sencha. What i have set up is a horizontal scrolling pannel with images attached to sub panels. This imitates a horizontal nav bar. Below that is a list that i call various stores based on a click event for any of the items in the scrolling menu. The problem I have is that I cant get the list to scroll. Even though scroll is set to true. It just occupies the space all of the items require. This list is docked to a root panel that it shares with the nav bar. Since someone can change the orientation I dont want to set a specific height for the list. If i do set it manually, the list scrolls fine. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was 2 parts. 1 I was not using a layout manager which caused everything not to re-size properly. the other issue is that I was creating my panels and items on the fly. I find Sencha touch to be much more responsive when you create all of your views up front and then hide and show them as needed